# mCustomScrollbar get scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

Iam using mCustomScrollbar , I want to know whether my scroll bar position is at bottom using jquery.How is that possible?Can i use ordinary bottom check usage in jquery or any functions are available in the mCustomScrollbar library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [callbacks example](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/callbacks_example.html) - there is *Scroll percentage* that displays % of scrolled. Open HTML source and you will see that it's uses *whileScrolling* callback: `$("#mcs-top-pct").text(this.mcs.topPct+"%");`, so when `this.mcs.topPct` is 100, then container is scrolled to bottom :)

Answer (score 4):

I used to myself something like:

`$('#someElement').mCustomScrollbar({theme: "minimal"});`

and after, you can get **scrollTop** using this code:

`var scrollTop = $('#someElement').find(".mCSB_dragger").position().top;`

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate scrollTop from dragger's top position:

```
    var $scrollerOuter  = $( '.mCustomScrollbar' );
    var $dragger        = $scrollerOuter.find( '.mCSB_dragger' );
    var scrollHeight    = $scrollerOuter.find( '.mCSB_container' ).height();
    var draggerTop      = $dragger.position().top;

    var scrollTop = draggerTop / ($scrollerOuter.height() - $dragger.height()) * (scrollHeight - $scrollerOuter.height());
```